# How can I merge two Pcollections(various sizes/data) with a common "key"(Street) via a side input?

Tags: python, merge, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam

I have two PCollections: one that pulls info from Pub/Sub, and one that pulls data from a CSV file. After some various transforms in each pipeline, I'd like to merge the two on a common key they both share, "STREET". I'm including the second PCollection as a side input. However, I'm getting an error on attempt to run.

I've attempted to utilize CoGroupByKey, but I kept receiving errors regarding the difference in types of data in the Pcollections. I tried refactoring the outputs, and setting the attribute of the PCollection via the `__setattr__` to force the types to be equal, but it reported "mixed values" regardless. After further research, it seems like it's better to utilize side inputs, especially when there's disparity in data size between elements. Even with side inputs, I'm still unable to get past the current error:

```
from_runner_api raise ValueError('No producer for %s' % id)
ValueError: No producer for ref_PCollection_PCollection_6
```

My application logic is as follows:

````
def merge_accidents(element, pcoll):
    print(element)
    print(pcoll)
    "some code that will append to existing data"

accident_pl = beam.Pipeline()
accident_data = (accident_pl |
                        'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('/modified_Excel_Crashes_Chicago.csv')
                        | 'Map Accidents' >> beam.ParDo(AccidentstoDict())
                        | 'Count Accidents' >> Count.PerKey())

chi_traf_pl = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
chi_traffic = (chi_traf_pl | 'ReadPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription_name, with_attributes=True)
                           | 'GeoEnrich&Trim' >> beam.Map(loc_trim_enhance)
                           | 'TimeDelayEnrich' >> beam.Map(timedelay)
                           | 'TrafficRatingEnrich' >> beam.Map(traffic_rating)
                           | 'MergeAccidents' >> beam.Map(merge_accidents, pcoll=AsDict(accident_data))
                           | 'Temp Write'>> beam.io.WriteToText('testtime', file_name_suffix='.txt'))

accident_pl.run()
chi_result = chi_traf_pl.run()
chi_result.wait_until_finish()```

**Pcoll 1:**
[{'segment_id': '1', 'street': 'Western Ave', 'direction': 'EB', 'length': '0.5', 'cur_traffic': '24', 'county': 'Cook County', 'neighborhood': 'West Elsdon', 'zip_code': '60629', 'evnt_timestamp': '2019-04-01 20:50:20.0', 'traffic_rating': 'Heavy', 'time_delay': '0.15'}]
**Pcoll 2:**
('MILWAUKEE AVE', 1)
('CENTRAL AVE', 2)
('WESTERN AVE', 6)

**Expected:**
[{'segment_id': '1', 'street': 'Western Ave', 'direction': 'EB', 'length': '0.5', 'cur_traffic': '24', 'county': 'Cook County', 'neighborhood': 'West Elsdon', 'zip_code': '60629', 'evnt_timestamp': '2019-04-01 20:50:20.0', 'traffic_rating': 'Heavy', 'time_delay': '0.15', 'accident_count': '6'}]

**Actual Results:**
"from_runner_api raise ValueError('No producer for %s' % id)ValueError: No producer for ref_PCollection_PCollection_6
````

Comment: Is this DirectRunner? Also just to check are you passing  --streaming as a option to the pipeline?

Comment: Thanks for the help! ! I'm using DirectRunner for testing right now. The intention is to use PubSub and Cloud Datastore as sources, run through Cloud Dataflow, and dump to BigQuery. I didn't want to keep using Dataflow to test my code, so I'm running DirectRunner on modified/smaller data sets until the code logic is solid. Streaming option is passed to the chi_traffic pipeline because of PubSub pulls. It will end up being a combination of streaming/batch processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. After looking through pipeline.py and the unittest source for side inputs, I realized that there's a check against the Pipeline object created.

I'm new to this and so I originally believed that you needed to create two separate Pipeline objects(streaming vs batch) so I could pass different options to both; i.e.streaming: True. That being said, I don't believe that is needed.

After consolidating them to a single object like below, the error went away and I was able to accept side inputs into the function:

'''

```
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
accident_data = (pipeline
                 | 'Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('modified_Excel_Crashes_Chicago.csv')
                 | 'Map Accidents' >> beam.ParDo(AccidentstoDict())
                 | 'Count Accidents' >> Count.PerKey())

chi_traffic = (pipeline
               | 'ReadPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=subscription_name, with_attributes=True)
               | 'GeoEnrich&Trim' >> beam.Map(loc_trim_enhance)
               | 'TimeDelayEnrich' >> beam.Map(timedelay)
               | 'TrafficRatingEnrich' >> beam.Map(traffic_rating)
               | 'MergeAccidents' >> beam.Map(merge_accidents, pcoll=pvalue.AsDict(accident_data))
               | 'Temp Write' >> beam.io.WriteToText('testtime',
                                                     file_name_suffix='.txt'))

chi_result = pipeline.run()
chi_result.wait_until_finish()
```

'''

Comment: Great!! But, How do you can use Streaming and Batch in the same pipeline without set mode stream for data from Pub/Sub?
Beam force us to use options.view_as(pipeline_options.StandardOptions).streaming = True 
But, if a set as True, I cant' create a batch pcollection, I got Transform node AppliedPTransform([7]: QueryTableStdSQL/Read/SDFBoundedSourceReader/ParDo(SDFBoundedSourceDoFn)/ProcessKeyedElements/GroupByKey/GroupByKey, _GroupByKeyOnly) was not replaced as expected.